# How to add event to an element inside iframe as a third party

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a survey platform to host various google form link from user, I hope to detect when a user have submitted the survey. When I have done is I inframe the survey link and try to add an eventListener to the submit button with class e19J0b CeoRYc.
However this failed as it is a cross-domain access.

```
function add_listen(){
            var button = document.getElementById("popup_preview").contentWindow.document.querySelector('.e19J0b.CeoRYc');
            button.addEventListener("click",SUBMIT);
        }
```

I have a function like this.
Is there other way that I implement this feature?
Thank you!

Comment: No this wont be possible as long as both documents do not share the same domain. This is a security feature by the browser developers and it is a basic feature. As long as you cannot edit the script in the i frame you wont be able to add an event listener

Comment: That's very sad, is there anyway I can achieve feature similar to what i wanted...

Comment: Yes, by creating the content of your iframe for yourself. Or ask the creators of the iframe to add the functionality.

Comment: huh, so i guess google form is not possible in this context? Will it be possible then if I put a button on my page and this button activate the submission in the iframe?

Comment: Do you have the rights to trigger the submission from another page within the iframe? You will run into the same issues there again I think. Better use a tool which fulfills your need.